# The significance of separate stack-space for threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have long known that Threads each have separate stack-space, but shared heap-memory.

But I recently found some code that made me question exactly what that meant.
Here is a shortened version of the code:

```
void SampleFunction()
{
    CRemoteMessage rmessage;
    rMessage.StartBackgroundAsync();   // Kickoff a background thread.

    /* Do other long-running work here... 
     * but don't leave function SampleFunction
     */

    rMessage.GetReply();   // Blocks if needed, but the message-background is mostly done by now.
    rMessage.ProcessReply();
}
```

In this code, the `rmessage` is a local, stack-variable, but spends most of its time in a background thread.  Is this safe?? How exactly is the background thread able to access the stack-variable of this thread?

Comment: What do you mean "how"? Your CPU implements memory reads, that's how...

Comment: It is safe.  The class uses the *this* pointer to access the object on the stack frame.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the stack and heap are part of the memory space that can be shared between threads. No one is preventing you from sharing stack addressed variables.

Each thread however has its own set of registers, including a stack pointer (and the derivatives), so you *can* maintain separate stacks if you need (otherwise it would be impossible), so the threads can call functions and do whatever they need. You can choose to break this separation if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion here is that you think of the stack of a thread as a separate entity that can only be accessed by the one thread. That's not how this works.

Every process has one large memory space to its use and *every* thread can read (and write!) *everything* in this space; the separation into stack-space and heap is a higher level design decision. For the background thread it doesn't matter whether the memory it receives is allocated on another thread's stack or on the heap.

There are even rare situations where you want to create a new stack for a thread yourself - makes no difference to the thread itself.

Comment: If I can say that. In same process, all threads' address space is different?

Comment: @Chuanhang. Threads don't have address spaces, processes have an address space and all the threads share the same.